# Adding numbers entered

Tags: python

What do I need to change to get the code to add the numbers for whichever number I enter (1,2,3)

```
total=0;
avg = 0;
print ("PACKAGE TYPES\n") 
print ("*****1 for 'The scenic tour,****") 
print ("*****2 for 'The relaxation_tour'**") 
print ("*****3 for 'Thejoyous_fun_tour'*")

for cost in range (10):
 package=int(input("please enter a number"))

if package == 1:
 cost = 119 
 
if package == 2:
 cost = 139 
 
if package == 3:
 cost = 149 

 total+=cost
 
avg = total / 10.0;

print ("The overall total cost of all trips made are:$", total) 
print ("Thee average cost is:$", avg)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to improve the code formatting and title — but please include more information about the output you expect, and the problem you are currently having. There are still some changes that need to be made to the formatting, since `total += cost` is not correctly indented, which is an error in Python.

Comment: Looks like `total+=cost` is indented; just un-indent it so `total` will always be set correctly.

Comment: Please fix the indentation so it's clear what the structure of the code is.  Use 4 spaces for each indentation level.  As shown here,  it seems that a lot of your code isn't in your `for` loop, but should be.  But maybe what you're running is different.  We all have to be in agreement as to what the indentation is of what you're actually running.

Comment: I would like the output to ask 10 users to enter a number. if the user enters 1 then the cost for the package should be $119, if they enter 2 the cost should be $139, and if the user enters 3 the cost=$149. Then the program should add all the numbers/ the number that is represented by the number entered by the 10 users and print the sum and average

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information and copy/paste your code *exactly* so the indentation is the same as what you are actually using. And don't forget to tell us **what the problem is**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get your indentation right, then your code does what you describe.  There are improvement that can be made, but it does work as is.  Here's the indentation of the code that allows it to work:

```
total = 0;
avg = 0;
print("PACKAGE TYPES\n")
print("*****1 for 'The scenic tour,****")
print("*****2 for 'The relaxation_tour'**")
print("*****3 for 'Thejoyous_fun_tour'*")

for cost in range(10):

    package = int(input("please enter a number"))

    if package == 1:
        cost = 119

    if package == 2:
        cost = 139

    if package == 3:
        cost = 149

    total += cost

    avg = total / 10.0;

print("The overall total cost of all trips made are:$", total)
print("Thee average cost is:$", avg)
```

Result:

```
PACKAGE TYPES

*****1 for 'The scenic tour,****
*****2 for 'The relaxation_tour'**
*****3 for 'Thejoyous_fun_tour'*
please enter a number1
please enter a number2
please enter a number3
please enter a number1
please enter a number2
please enter a number3
please enter a number1
please enter a number2
please enter a number3
please enter a number1
The overall total cost of all trips made are:$ 1340
Thee average cost is:$ 134.0
```

If you have the indentation like it is here, and yet you are having problems, then you need to better describe what those problems are.

Comment: Thank youuu, it was just my indentation